# how does else if statment work inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I had a challenge that says :

- you have an array of these items :

  `const items = ["gold cup", "puppy", "sword", "whale's tooth", "squid tentacle"];`
- and this array shows items’ price respectively :

  ```
  const prices = [5, 4, 10, 20, 100];
  ```
- every price of an item isn't mentioned in the items array is equal to 1

create a function that calculate the value "the price " of some chosen items which are located in ChosenItem array.
So I used nested for loop and used if and **else if** statments. it worked fine but it doesnt add 1 for every unmentioned item . and it adds more than 1.
here's the code :

```js
const items = ["gold cup", "puppy", "sword", "whale's tooth", "squid tentacle"];
const prices = [5, 4, 10, 20, 100];

let TotalPrice = 0;
let ChosenIems = ["puppy", "sword", "eagle eye"];

function PricesCalculator() {
  for (i = 0; i < ChosenIems.length; i++) {
    for (x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
      if (ChosenIems[i] === items[x]) {
        TotalPrice += prices[x];
      } else if (ChosenIems[i] !== items[x]) {
        TotalPrice += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return TotalPrice;
}
console.log(PricesCalculator(), TotalPrice);
```

Comment: Where are the prices Array in your PricesCalculator function?

Comment: Why don't you just [debug it?](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript)

Comment: @Alex I had used it inside the if statment    `if (ChosenIems[i] === items[x]) {
        TotalPrice += prices[x];`

Comment: @Abdounabdou that is entirely correct the problem is the if else. Every time your condition is not true you are incrementing per iteration 2 times which is not correct you'll just check at the end if it is not included. And then increment by one

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `else` part of your `if-else` statement.

The `if-else` statement is inside the for loop that is comparing each element in the `items` array with the current item in the `ChosenItems` array. As there are 5 elements in the `items` array, the loop will run five times and on each loop it's evaluating which part of the if statement to go into - either the top because it found the `chosenItem`, or the `else` because it didn't. Because the else doesn't have a condition it will **always** execute the `else` if the `if` condition isn't true. In other words, your code will add 1 to the `TotalPrice` on every loop where the `ChosenItem` doesn't match the current `item` in the list.

To fix it you can add a bool value to track whether or not you found the `ChosenItem` and once you've looped through everything in the `item` array and compared it to the `ChosenItem` you can test whether or not the `chosenItem` was found and then add 1 to the `TotalPrice` (outside of the nested loop) if it wasn't.

Remove the else from the if-else statement so that you're not adding 1 on every loop.

You could also add a `break;` command when the `ChosenItem` has been found to break out of the inner for loop because you don't need to continue to try and find the current `ChosenItem`, you can move onto the next one.

```js
const items = ["gold cup", "puppy", "sword", "whale's tooth", "squid tentacle"];
const prices = [5, 4, 10, 20, 100];

let TotalPrice = 0;
let ChosenIems = ["puppy", "sword", "eagle eye"];

function PricesCalculator() {
  //variable to keep track of it you found the current chosen item
  let foundItem = false;
  for (i = 0; i < ChosenIems.length; i++) {
    //reset because we're starting a new chosen item.
    foundItem = false;
    for (x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
      if (ChosenIems[i] === items[x]) 
      {
        TotalPrice += prices[x];
        //found the ChosenItem so set to true
        foundItem = true;
        //stop executing this for loop because we found the ChosenItem
        break;
      }
    }
    //if we didn't find the ChosenItem then add one to the TotalPrice
    if(!foundItem)
       TotalPrice += 1;
  }
  return TotalPrice;
}
console.log(PricesCalculator(), TotalPrice);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do the +1 inside the else of the inner for-loop then it will do the increment multiple times always when the condition is not true.

You can check in the outer loop if it isn't in items and then do the increment by one

```js
const items = ["gold cup", "puppy", "sword", "whale's tooth", "squid tentacle"];
const prices = [5, 4, 10, 20, 100];
let TotalPrice = 0;
let ChosenIems = ["puppy", "sword", "eagle eye"];

function PricesCalculator() {



  for (let i = 0; i < ChosenIems.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      if (ChosenIems[i] === items[j]) {
        TotalPrice += prices[j]
      }
    }
    if (!items.includes(ChosenIems[i])) {
      TotalPrice++
    }
  }
  return TotalPrice;
}
console.log(PricesCalculator());
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you need:

```
function PricesCalculator() {
  for (i = 0; i < ChosenIems.length; i++) {
    for (x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
      if (ChosenIems[i] === items[x]) {
        TotalPrice += prices[x];
      }
    }
    if (!items.includes(ChosenIems[i]))TotalPrice += 1;
  }
  return TotalPrice;
}
```

Comment: Why not? It's a much cleaner solution and does the right thing.